# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I tried lots of solutions on this website, nothing worked for me, 
the error accrued when I try to add firebase. and I can't find a dependency which use play-service. please help

The error and app dependencies:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, but i do this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' //use this version as the newest version
    }
```

and i did this too

```
 dependencies {
.
.
.
    //    compile project(':google-play-services') comment because this version isn't same with my firebase version, try to get the last google-play-service jar / compile the last version
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'){
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'com.google.android.gms'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // i do it on every project i have
```

then sync aand clean your project
may this help you, i think the version of google-play-service should be same as the firebase version

update

try to delete your old `google-service-play_lib`
and add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' //use the newest`

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'projects-1'
..........
..........
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and build the gradle again.

Comment: After removing it, It still getting the same error, How I get more details of my Library

Comment: Still no luck- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__FZmkvWnRMWXNCZW91MF84UUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @supuldulanka why you are compiling this line .."compile project:'googleplayservice..'??